# SharePoint search - No items returned

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

SharePoint search is not working which means no items are returned. How do I troubleshot this?

1. Crawl log looks good. All the items are crawled
2. incremental crawl is running as scheduled

What else do I need to look for?

Comment: Can you please provide more details, the details in the question is insufficient.

Comment: users used to be able to search and results would appear. and now all of the sudden no results. I am new to SharePoint administer (very small company and I am helpdesk but not I have take on this role as well)

Comment: Perform an Index Reset and then do a full crawl again and check if this solves your problems.

Comment: Reset is done, re-crawled and problems still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that search application's service account password was change so all I had to do is to change the password and everything is good now.

Answer (score 0):

Try if these steps helps you

1. Go to Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications -> Search
2. You will see a link to your Content Sources. If you edit that it
   will give you the opportunity to setup a schedule for both Full and
   Incremental indexing
3. You can run a full crawl, once completed you will have results
   if everything is configured correctly

Comment: Everything that you said are already present. Crawl logs look good. What's the next step?